# Print ArrayList(My Datatype) using For Each Loop Not Working

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code of UserDetail class.

```
public class UserDetail {

    public void user_detail() {

        Members m1=new Members("Rashid Faheem","0312-6193172","House No. 430, Street No. 5 Mehmood Abad Pindora, Rawalpindi");
        Members m2=new Members("Yawar Hayat","0312-6193172", "RajanPur");
        Members m3=new Members("Azhar Malik", "0312-6193172", "RajanPur");
        Members m4=new Members("Muhammad Ali", "0312-6193172", "RajanPur");
        Members m5=new Members("Muhammad Nazik", "0312-6193172", "RajanPur");

        ArrayList<Members> al = new ArrayList<Members>();

        al.add(m1);
        al.add(m2);
        al.add(m3);
        al.add(m4);
        al.add(m5);

        System.out.println("These are our Members.");

        For (Members m:al) {

            System.out.println(m.getName());
        }


    }


}
```

Here is code from Members Class which I am using as DataType in ArrayList.

```
public class Members {

    private String name, phone,address;


    public Members(String name, String phone, String address) {
        name=name;
        phone=phone;
        address=address;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

**Update**
I changed my code according to your advice but another problem now. I am only getting name but not phone and address.

Output

```
These are our Members.
Rashid Faheem
Yawar Hayat
Azhar Malik
Muhammad Ali
Muhammad Nazik
```

Comment: `java` is case-sensitive, so `For` won't work for you. `for` (lowercase) is the keyword you need, so just change that and it should work

Comment: Instead of updating your question to include a completely separate issue, you should create a new question. Your question was answered appropriately multiple times between your "updates".

Comment: Agree. I am trying to ask another question but it gives me time period of 90 min to ask another question. Thats why i updated it again and again. Waiting for that 90 min to pass to ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (Members m:al) {

    System.out.println(m.getName());
}
```

Notice the lowercase `f`. Just a typo.

EDIT:

Your constructor is also just assigning the constructor arguments to themselves. You need to assign the constructor arguments to the class variables.

```
public Members(String name, String phone, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.address = address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace For by for.
And update Members with additionnal this :

```
public Members(String name, String phone, String address) 
{
    this.name=name;
    this.phone=phone;
    this.address=address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two syntax errors. Once you correct them you should be able to print the members list:

1. for not For.

   ```
   for (Members m : al) {
       System.out.println(m.getName());
   }
   ```
2. Members constructor. The code is not assigning the parameters to the member variables.

   ```
   public Members(String name, String phone, String address) {
       this.name=name;
       this.phone=phone;
       this.address=address;    
   }
   ```

Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should stick to the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - so your method `user_detail` should be named `userDetail`. You might want to consider naming it `print` as that's what it is supposed to do.

Next, the constructor in your `Members` class does nothing, since you miss the `this.` as prefix of the *left side* of your operation. So you would want to write it like this (as mentioned by *WatchdogReset*):

```
public Members(String name, String phone, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.address = address;
}
```

Another problem is the typo in `For` which is supposed to be `for` (stated by *ninnemank*).

I refactored your code, to show you a possible way of doing what you want - of course this is rather opinionated and not a perfect solution.

**Members**

```
public class Members {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    public Members(String name, String phone, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.join(" / ", this.getName(), this.getPhone(), this.getAddress());
    }
}
```

**UserDetail**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDetail {
    private List<Members> members;

    public UserDetail() {
        this.members = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addMember(Members member){
        return this.members.add(member);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.members.stream()
                .map(member -> member.toString())
                .reduce((a, b) -> String.join(System.lineSeparator(), a, b))
                .orElse("");
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Members m1 = new Members("Rashid Faheem", "0312-6193172", "House No. 430, Street No. 5 Mehmood Abad Pindora, Rawalpindi");
        Members m2 = new Members("Yawar Hayat", "0312-6193172", "RajanPur");
        Members m3 = new Members("Azhar Malik", "0312-6193172", "RajanPur");
        Members m4 = new Members("Muhammad Ali", "0312-6193172", "RajanPur");
        Members m5 = new Members("Muhammad Nazik", "0312-6193172", "RajanPur");

        UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();

        userDetail.addMember(m1);
        userDetail.addMember(m2);
        userDetail.addMember(m3);
        userDetail.addMember(m4);
        userDetail.addMember(m5);

        System.out.println("These are our Members.");
        System.out.println(userDetail);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
These are our Members.
Rashid Faheem / 0312-6193172 / House No. 430, Street No. 5 Mehmood Abad Pindora, Rawalpindi
Yawar Hayat / 0312-6193172 / RajanPur
Azhar Malik / 0312-6193172 / RajanPur
Muhammad Ali / 0312-6193172 / RajanPur
Muhammad Nazik / 0312-6193172 / RajanPur
```

Comment: `UserDetail` is not an appropriate method name as standard conventions are camelCase. It should be `userDetail`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing that out - not sure what I was thinking when typing that.